# How to store viewstate and which storage would be better to store?

Tags: c#, asp.net, viewstate

can you give me example or source, how to store Viewstate to memory or to session? Is it possible to save it anywhere else?

I know that you can save it in session applying this code

```
SessionPageStatePersister(Page)
```

Comment: u can store anywhere but scope of viewstate is for only that particular page.

Comment: Refer this https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/ms972976.aspx